# How to undo svn revision that is not latest?

Tags: svn

I would like to undo a `svn` revision which is not the latest in the log. There are a number of file changes within the revision and one has been overwritten by a more recent change while all the other ones have my change as the latest.

So it is a scenario of moderate difficulty. Not only is the revision that I want to take out not on top of the log but it also contains file changes that have been updated since by other users.

Can you advise how to perform such a reversion in a graceful manner, meaning the most minimal series of steps involved?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create and apply a *reverse* patch. For example, following sequence of commands reverts changes introduced in revision 925. Conflicts may happen as usual and you will have to resolve them by editing patch file.

```
svn diff -r 925:924 > rev.patch   # diff bad revision with previous one
svn patch --dry-run rev.patch     # check for conflicts
svn patch rev.patch               # actual patching
svn commit
```

Comment: What? Diff? Patch? There is a single command for undoing changes: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo

Answer (score 0):

You could just run `svn merge ^/MyProject/trunk . -c-123` to revert revision *123*. Don't forget to commit this change and provide a log message.

Read [SVNBook | Undoing changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).